# Freeing memory outside of its allocated area

Tags: c, pointers, free

Evening all,

In the C programming language I am messing with pointers and I keep on getting segmentation the  (core dumped) error. Clearly some of my code is messed up. Here is some example code (but not my actual code) of what I am doing. Note that I am returning a local pointer in one of the functions.

```
struct foo* new_foo ( )
{
    struct foo myfoo;
    return &myfoo;
}

void free_foo ( struct foo* myfoo )
{
     // pnt_var is being used on another part
     // of the program so we can't free it yet
    foo->ptr_var = NULL;
    free(foo);
}
```

So my question is, how I properly free a segment of memory through a function, without freeing that structure's allocated memory (which is still active in other parts of the program). I am implementing lists if that helps at all.

Comment: have you considered checking if its null or not before you free ?

Comment: "Note that I am returning a local pointer in one of the functions."  **Don't do that**.  Also don't call free() on something allocated on the stack, even *during* it's lifetime.

Comment: @Raiyan No, I have not. Doesn't free() do nothing if it is already a null value?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I asked

Comment: @user2958652 NULL is defined as `(void *)0`, which is also a VALID address, and cannot be accessed in user code. This is why it segfaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myfoo` is a stack allocated `struct`. You might have to `malloc()` the struct dynamically and then access the struct outside `new_foo`

like this:

```
struct foo *new_foo(){ return malloc(sizeof(struct foo));}
```

And `free()` on an un`malloc`ed pointer is undefined behavior, if you're lucky you get away with segmentation fault, if you were unlucky and on windows 98, your PC would blue screen

Comment: So malloc & friends should be the only way I create structure "objects"?

Comment: if you want them to be available OUTSIDE the function scope then yes.

Comment: There was another answer that I believe had good information, but I suppose someone deleted it. It mentioned that once the function call is finished, the locally defined variable is automatically freed and therefore any pointer to its address is pointing to random memory. Anyways, I want to choose this answer as the best answer but don't know how.

Comment: Minor detail that your answer implicitly states. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: There must be a green check mark below the answer points.. that's how you select it.